# Make a pretty table in Python 3.4 without add-ons

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a noob, so this is probably really easy.  In Python 3.4, I'm trying to print out a well-formatted multiplication table.  The multiplication works, but I can't seem to get it formatted.  What am I doing wrong?

```
def multTable():
    maximum_value = int(input("How big of a multiplication table should I make?\n"))
    for x in range(1, maximum_value + 1):
        for y in range (1, maximum_value + 1):
            print('{0:2d}'.format(x*y))

multTable()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `print` again, it outputs to a new line. Instead what you should do is form the string for your multiplication table, and then output the whole thing at the end. In my example I used tabs in the rows, and then after each row started a new line:

```
def multTable():
    maximum_value = int(input("How big of a multiplication table should I make?\n"))
    table = ''
    for x in range(1, maximum_value + 1):
        for y in range (1, maximum_value + 1):
            table = '\t'.join((table,'{0:2d}'.format(x*y)))
        table = '\n'.join((table, '\n'))
    print(table)
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks, and your explanation made a ton of sense to me.